# How do I reference array elements in an object array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an object array, created by deserialising a serialized object array:

```
object[] jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(json);
```

Contains:

```
{[3,"2016-06-11T08:35:00","Fleet Discussion ",1,"Maintenance"]}
{[7,"2016-07-14T09:45:00","Fleet Discussion, MX Issues",1,"Maintenance"]}
{[8,"2016-08-18T08:30:00","Fleet Discussion, APU",1,"Maintenance"]}
```

That looks like an array of objects containing arrays.

I use the following iterator:

```
foreach (object item in jsonData) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Each item is extracted, so that for each item, I have an object containing an array:

```
{[3,"2016-06-11T08:35:00","Fleet Discussion ",1,"Maintenance"]}
```

However, any attempt to use item[0], is an error (Cannot index object with []).

So, how do I reference the array elements inside the object?  Or, how do I extract the array from the object?

**EDIT: FURTHER DETAILS:**

Here is how the serialized object is created.  Hope this helps:

```
private List<object> _Meetings = new List<object>{};
private string _Meetings_JSON = null;
```

(There are getters/setters for these private fields.)

Then Later:

```
if (rs.HasRows) {

    while (rs.Read()) {

        object[] rec = new object[5];

        rec[MEETING_ID] =           (int) rs[MEETING_ID];
        rec[MEETING_DATETIME] =     (DateTime) rs[MEETING_DATETIME];
        rec[AGENDA] =               (string) rs[AGENDA];
        rec[MEETING_TYPE_ID] =      (int) rs[MEETING_TYPE_ID];
        rec[MEETING_TYPE] =         (string) rs[MEETING_TYPE];

        _Meetings.Add(rec);

    }

    _Meeting_JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_Meetings);

}
```

Comment: What does the original json look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

item is an object, not an array.  Access it using `item` without the [0].

**EDIT BASED ON FURTHER INFO**

I would rewrite entirely.  Create a class for your Meeting Object as such:

```
public class Meeting
{
    public int meetingID { get; set; }
    public DateTime meetingDateTime { get; set; }
    public String agenda { get; set; }
    public int meetingTypeId { get; set; }
    public String meetingType { get; set; }
}
```

when reading use this:

```
private List<Meeting> _Meetings = new List<Meeting>{};
//...

while (rs.Read()) {

    Meeting rec = new Meeting() {
        meetingID = rs[MEETING_ID],
        meetingDateTime = rs[MEETING_DATETIME],
        agenda = rs[AGENDA],
        meetingTypeId = rs[MEETING_TYPE_ID],
        meetingType = rs[MEETING_TYPE]
    };

    _Meetings.Add(rec);

}
```

then you should have a Meeting object you can reference in your foreach:

```
Meeting[] jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Meeting[]>(json);

foreach (Meeting item in jsonData) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: if you are looking to extract elements within that object and what you have shown is what the data looks like, it will need to be formatted into proper json.

Comment: OK, so item..... what?  The array elements have no names, so I can't do item.MeetingID.  It looks like I either need to be able to extract the array from the object first.  Or find some way to reference the array elements from inside the object.  What syntax will do that?

Comment: The value is merely a string now, you could use String.Split and remove the leading and trailing symbols and access the String Array passed back.  Or if you can get the original data in json format so you can cast it as an object to reference by property.

Comment: How would it know what the meetingID is?  There is no meetingID property on a generic Object.

Comment: "How would it know what the meetingID is?"...Exactly. -  I have an object that contains an array:  {[3,"2016-06-11T08:35:00","Fleet Discussion ",1,"Maintenance"]}.   How do I get the array out of the object?  Or am I misreading that?  The "[]" square brackets mean it's an array.  When I set a breakpoint in the VS debugger, and hover over the "item" object, it tells me that it's type is "Array".  So, there's gotta be a way to get that array out into a proper array type.  Sure appreciate your help, here, BTW.  ;-)

Comment: You are declaring it as a generic object.  Try using your object type.  IE...`Meeting[] jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Meeting[]>(json);` and/or changing your foreach to `...(Meeting item...`

Comment: Check out my edit.  I included how the object was created in the first place.  it may help you understand what it contains and what I am trying to get.  Thanks again.

Comment: that's a way better idea!  I will definitely do that.  Thanks.  Also, I assume the "[]" should not be on "Meeting[] jsonData = ....."?

Comment: It should still be necessary as you are getting a list (or array) of Meeting objects.

Answer (score 0):

`item` is just a single instance of `object` from your array `jsonData`.  You can't do `item[0]` because it's not an array itself.  If you want to use it, just use `item` by itself, i.e. no brackets.

If, on the other hand, the `object` is actually a more-derived type that is a collection or an array itself, then you can cast it and use it like this:

```
((MoreDerivedCollectionType) item)[0]
```